# AWS Lambda : Download Deployment Package option missing in Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

There is a recent update made in the UI of AWS Lambda Function console and the Download Deployment Package button that use to download the function code as .zip is now missing.

Previously, under Action Button --> Export function use to give two option either download the AWS SAM file or Download Deployment Package.

[image]

[image]

The console update only allows to download the AWS SAM file.
[image]

Is this feature removed from console or I'm i missing something?

Comment: The button "Download function" should download the .zip file, if your package type is zip. To get to the SAM template, you can click the "Template" tab under the Function Overview.

Comment: I can't see it either. It was there a few days back for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button "Download function" download both AWS SAM yaml file and code base as .zip file.

Make sure your browser allows multiple file download option. If its blocked only the SAM yaml file will be downloaded.

Example : Google Chrome browser
[image]

Also Contacted AWS Technical Support, confirmed the same.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I couldn't get it work in safari. Worked in chrome.